# Rails Associations - Multiple users fulfilling different roles for single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm struggling with associations today.

I have 2 models

```
User
Match
```

A match is initiated by a userA and has an opponent, userB

I need to be able to distinguish which user created the match and which is the opposer so simple `has_many` & `belongs_to` isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i would do something like this:

on my create Match action i would create the match like this

Match controller:

```
def create
   @match= Match.new(params[:match])
   @match.creator_id = current_user.id 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @match.save
        format.html    
      else
        format.html
      end
    end
end
```

asuming you are using something like devise and that the match model has both of the users and one is the creator_id

Comment: Thanks!  By using 2 different foreign keys I got right on track. It turned out that using a different foreign key in the User model was the piece I was missing - by adding   has_many :created_matches, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :opposing_matches, :foreign_key => :opponent_id, :class_name => "Match"  - to the User model i was able to get all the right associations working for build methods, yay!  thanks again, sometimes just a crack to the noggin is all that's needed.